# Unable to add tooltip, onmouseover, etc events to components created on RunTime

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I am facing a weird situation here. I am unable to add tooltips, mouse (click,mouseover,mouseout) events to a runtime created button inside a container(HBox).

This init() function executes under creationComplete event.

```
private function init():void
{
for(var i:int=0;i<5;i++)
{
myButton = new Button();
myButton.id="mBtn"+i;
myButton.label="Test";
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onDblClick);
camCont.addChildAt(myButton,i); //camCont is the HBox control
}
}

protected function onDblClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
Alert.show("Click event works !!!");
}
```

When this application is executed, the 5 buttons are created, but click event is not fired. Can someone guide me where am i going wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: If possible, show more of your code or recreate this problem in a very simple app (and show that). There doesn't appear to be anything wrong w/the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code (this works!):

//Code

```
public function init():void{
        var btn:Button = new Button();
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showAlert);
    container.addChild(btn);
}

private function showAlert(event:Event):void{
    Alert.show("CLICK!!!");
}
```

//MXML

```
<mx:HBox id="container"/>
```

You can try [here](https://github.com/gastonf/GRepo/blob/master/ButtonClickEvent/Test.swf?raw=true). The source code is [here](https://github.com/gastonf/GRepo/tree/master/ButtonClickEvent/Src).
I hope it will be helpful.